# How to make substitutions in string only after a certain anchor?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

How to make substitutions in string only after certain anchor?

I need:

```
xtop.xnext.sig1 --> xtop.xnext-sig1
xtop.xnext.xlower.sig2 --> xtop.xnext-xlower-sig2
```

With an elegant `s///` in Perl. Is there a cool way to do this using `xtop.xnext` as the anchor (i.e., all '.' --> '-' but only after `xtop.xnext`) rather than first matching and then stitching using multiple commands?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using first a match to set the starting position using the `g` flag which sets the `pos` property of `$str`, which can be later used with the `\G` assertion to start the search at a given position:

```
if ( $str =~ /xtop\.xnext/g ) {
    $str =~ s/\G[^.]*\K\./-/g;
}
```

See [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information.

Comment: This will require the `.` to immediately follow the last match though. You want it anytime after the last match, you can insert `[^.]*` to allow non-dot characters in between and follow with `\K` so those characters are not substituted. `s/\G[^.]*\K\./-/g`

Comment: @Grinnz Thanks for advice! I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
perl -p -e 's/(?:xtop\.xnext|\G)\K\.([^.]+)/-$1/g;'

(?:  -- grouping only, don't create backref
xtop.\xnext|\G   -- explicit text or position of last match
\K     -- match from this position only
\.     -- match the period
([^.]+)   -- capture for the purpose of the \G to be used later
```